# Jquery: Target part of a text node on a second line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know if this is possible. I have an h2 tag with some text:

```
<div>
    <h2>Here Goes a Big Sample Slider</h2>
</div>
```

It is a big font in a short width div.

```
h2{
    font-size: 69px
}
div{
    width: 600px;
}
```

So it breaks up into 2 lines. Here is a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Qypv/

I would like to always target the second line in the sentence, no matter what the sentence is(It will be user generated), so I can wrap it in a span and give it some properties. I cannot change the HTML directly, though.

Thank you

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-line/  lets you change the look. well, it lets you reset the look after applying 2nd-line props to the whole H2... if that's not enough, you can split the h2 text by space and wrap a span around each one, then compare the $.offset().top of each span to find the 2nd row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [:first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line) pseudo-element to do something like:

```
 h2:first-line { /* Normal style */
        font-size: 69px
 }
 h2 { /* Second line */
        font-size:13px;
 }
```

**<kbd>[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/F3QE3/)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank, this worked. I didn't know this pseudo selector. Learn something new every day